# How do I add external files to a Gradle distribution in a location other than root?

Tags: gradle

I have an application built in Gradle, and it has a number of parameters defined in a configuration file (config.yaml) in the base project directory. When I distribute the application, unzip it, and run the batch file from the *bin* directory it expects this file (config.yaml) to be in the *bin* folder.

I have had a lot of trouble getting the distribution to add the file to bin. Instead, I add it to the base directory (the same directory as *bin*).

[image]

It seems like it must be simple, but I have read through the docs and I can't find an option to change where the file is placed. I am clearly missing something. This is the relevant portion of my build.gradle (with company info removed):

```
group 'org...'
version '1.0...'

plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'distribution'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

application {
    mainClass = 'server.Server'
}

distributions {
    main {
        distributionBaseName = 'data-processor'
        contents {
            from 'config.yaml'
        }
    }
}

dependencies { ...
```

How do I get this to add the "config.yaml" file to bin instead of the current location?

Comment: Would something like this work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815349/how-to-copy-file-in-gradle ?

Comment: I think this is the right direction. "into" is for sure the correct operation, but when I try something like "into 'bin' it creates a bin directory before any of the other stuff is created.  so I have the rest of the project nested in an extra bin folder. Maybe there is some way to move it later in the lifecycle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the contents out into separate statements for each file using `applicationDistribution.from()` was what eventually worked.

```
applicationDistribution.from("config.yaml") {
    into "bin"
}
```

I think this is related to the life cycle, and the "into" operation in the above statement happens after the distribution file structure is created.